# Need Help Opening chntpw

Tags: windows-xp

I,m trying to unlock windows on my computer so I can download some software. The directions I got say to open up http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/chntpw, but when I tried to, Ubuntu said I had asked for more than one package, it was an error message.

Comment: =Lucid=? How-to's and FAQ's for a 6 year old OS that also went EOL is not the path to take. 1. please provide the "directions" and 2. "an error message"? Come on. Provide the error message.

Comment: and why would you need Ubuntu to unlock windows? Windows has tools for this.

Comment: Windows XP???  That went EOL in 2014!

Comment: @AndroidDev its support has ended, not end of life.

Comment: @ƎpᴉʇʎXD End of support is the same thing as EOL

Comment: @ƎpᴉʇʎXD: Since software is basically information and information doesn't cease to exist in the typical sense, that's not what we mean by “end of life” when talking about software. Rather, “life” refers to the *life cycle of software development*, starting with its design and implementation, then deployment and maintenance, and finally the end of maintenance, the point from whereon officially nobody takes care of it and its users any longer.

Comment: “An error message” can usually be avoided with “an action”. ;-) What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask)) Also, Ubuntu Lucid isn't supported any longer by Canonical or the community and therefore off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

The directions you got were more than three years out of date (since Lucid (Ubuntu 10.04) reached EOL in May 2013). The URL you are looking for is this: http://packages.ubuntu.com/chntpw, but that said, the better installation method is to run this command in terminal:

```
sudo apt install chntpw
```